# Calling function from right parent class with multiple inheritance in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have two classes `A` and `B` and both have a method `get_type()` that returns a string and which is called in the `__init__()` of both classes to set an instance attribute `self.type`. Now there's a child class that inherits from both `A` and `B` and in it's `__init__()` it takes an instance of either `A` or `B` as an argument. Depending on whether it's instantiated with an instance of `A` or `B`, I call the corresponding `__init__()` of the parent. Presumably because of the lookup order of multiple inheritance, always the `get_type()` method of the `A` parent is called, even if `C` is instantiated with an instance of `B`. See code below:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = self.get_type()
    def get_type(self):
        return 'A'
class B: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = self.get_type()
    def get_type(self):
        return 'B'
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, instance):
        if isinstance(instance, A):
            A.__init__(self)
            print('Inheriting from A')
        else:
            B.__init__(self)
            print('Inheriting from B')
            
a = A()
b = B()
c = C(b)
print(a.type, b.type, c.type)

>>> Inheriting from B
>>> A B A
```

So I want that `c.type` is 'B' since it inherited from the `B` class. Can I maybe use the `super()` function to get the behaviour I want?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. When you use multiple inheritance, you need to call all the superclasses' `__init__()` methods, because other inherited methods may depend on those initializations.

Comment: Hey @Barmar, here's it's more like an either or situation. In my real code A and B both inherit from an abstract class and each has its own implementation for a bunch of methods.

Comment: This isn't how object oriented design works and based on your comment this sounds like an X/Y problem.

Comment: @woodford not sure I get what you mean. So the reasoning for that structure is something like this: There are two classes that represent 'two flavours' of a more general model. But it's always flavor one or two, so the general model is implemented as an abstract class and both share a bunch of methods, but have their own as well. Now I C is basically an extension of either flavor one or two. It's again one of the two flavors but builds on that with some additional input. And again, it makes use of a bunch of methods that are defined in the abstract, general class (which is not in this example)

Comment: @woodford But i'm always open to suggestions for better software design. Still, I wonder whether I can get the desired behaviour with a structure like I gave above.

Comment: "Now there's a child class that inherits from both A and B and in it's __init__() it takes an instance of either A or B as an argument. Depending on whether it's instantiated with an instance of A or B, I call the corresponding __init__() of the paren" This doesn't make any sense. You shouldn't be using multiple inheritance here. Use delegation and composition

Comment: "Can I maybe use the super() function to get the behaviour I want?" no, that is for cooperative multiple inheritance, where every class in the inheritance hierarchy calls `super` and *all* the methods in the method resolution order end up getting called. What you are describing here is not what you would use `super` for. You *could* use `super` to get there, but it's essentially going to look like what you already have, and you are basically going against what super does, i.e., gives you the *next* method in the method resolution order (you want to *ignore* that order)

Comment: hey @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the answer. Ok, so I heard of composition before. But I guess that is usually used to avoid having too many different subclasses, no? The thing is that the child class behaves again like either class A or B, but it has some additional shared functionality. What would delegation mean in this context?

Comment: @Pickniclas no, composition is just the most basic thing you can do. `self.attribute = 1` is technically composition. Delegation means you *delegate* behavior to one of the attributes you have. Note, you are *always* inheriting *both* from `A` and `B`, you can't choose what to inherit from, inheritance applies to the *type* not a particular instance. The type already inherits from both, because oyu used multiple inheritance

Comment: So, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56746709/can-i-choose-the-parent-class-of-a-class-from-a-fixed-set-of-parent-classes-cond/56747123#56747123) to a related question I answered from a whjile back where someone wanted to tried to use multiple inheritance to mean "inherit from A *or* B" (but multiple inheritance always means "inheritr from A **and** B"). I showed a basic example of delegation (which Python makes relatively easy with `__getattr__`)

Comment: OK, thanks for the reference. I mean one easy workaround would be to replace `self.type = self.get_type()` by `self.type = 'A'`. It would then give me the desired behaviour. But I prefer the `get_type()` version, because it is actually an abstarct method. So if I'd ever have another class that C inherits from there must be a 'get_type()' method implemented and I get an error if I forget it.

Answer (score 0):

The *why* you are doing that apart, here is what you are asking for:

When you have colliding (or potentially colliding)  method names, Python's mechanism to avoid that is prefix the method name with two underscores (`__`). Most articles and 3rdy party docs on Python refer to this as "the way to create a private attribute/method in Python". It is really not that: Python does not make use of private attributes at all, but for convention (which is using a single `_` as prefix.

Using two underscores, instead of one, triggers and internal name transformation of the method or attribute, which adds the class name as a prefix to the target method, in a transparent way. This is called "name mangling".

In the case of your code, it will work out of the box with no further changes. If you inspect the running code (`print(dir(self))`, for example), you will see that your methods will be named `A._A__get_type` and `B._B__get_type`, respectively (and both methods will be present in `C`)

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = self.__get_type()
    def __get_type(self):
        return 'A'
class B: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = self.__get_type()
    def __get_type(self):
        return 'B'
```

However, see that any method in `C` would not be able to "see" `.get_type`: that method is now "private" to each superclass. Both are reachable from C with their transformed names, if used explicitly, tough.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to do some kind of *conditional inheritance*, here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65754399/conditional-inheritance-based-on-arguments-in-python), *conditional inheritance* can be considered an anti-pattern because it can make code harder to understand and maintain, anyways you can implement that with some know patterns like *Wrapper/Decorator* pattern, there is a very good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56746709/can-i-choose-the-parent-class-of-a-class-from-a-fixed-set-of-parent-classes-cond/56747123#56747123) of that in the comments. Another pattern you can use is the *Composition* pattern, here is an example:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = self.get_type()

    def get_type(self):
        return 'A'

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = self.get_type()

    def get_type(self):
        return 'B'

class C:
    @classmethod
    def composed_width(cls, Klass, *args, **kwargs):
        class Composed(cls, Klass):
            pass
        return Composed(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_type_wrapped(self):
        return f'WrappedType[{self.get_type()}]'


c_a = C.composed_width(A)
c_b = C.composed_width(B)

print(c_a.type, c_a.get_type_wrapped())
print(c_b.type, c_b.get_type_wrapped())

>>> A WrappedType[A]
>>> B WrappedType[B]
```

The method `get_type_wrapped` is just to give an example of a *shared* method, the idea is just to create a local class that *composes* the class `C` and another class passed as a parameter, and returns an instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what your goal is. First, let's look at why your approach is flawed though:

### Problem With The Current Approach

As per your class layout, a `C` is both an `A` and a `B`. The reason is that inheritance forms an "is a" relation. From that, the implied expectation is that the relation fulfills the "Liskov Substitution Principle", i.e. that you can provide a `C` wherever code expects an `A` or a `B`. I believe that this not your intention, although close.

### Possible Alternative Approach

You mentioned in the comments that both `A` and `B` have a common interface, maybe even implemented as an abstract base class (https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html). Let's call it `I` (as in **I**nterface) to make discussion easier. It doesn't matter if it exists as ABC or is just a convention (classes providing similar methods a.k.a. "Duck Typing"), Python is permissive in this area.

With that interface `I`, we actuall have these three classes that all three implement this interface. If you now write your code to expect an `I` (instead of concrete `A` or `B`), you should be able to pass either of `A`, `B`, or `C` to it (again, Liskov Substitution).

Further, `C` doesn't have to inherit both `A` and `B`, it can contain one of the two instead. Actually, it could simply contain an `I`, to make it easier to extend to further such types in the future. Any method required by `I` (you only have `get_type()` in your sketch) can be implemented by simply forwarding it to the contained `I` instance.

### Notes

- Why `C` in the first place? I have my doubts whether this needs to be a class at all. Not everything is a class and not everything should be one! My guess is that large parts are made obsolete by a common abstract base class. The only real advantage I could see is the ability to exchange the underlying `A` or `B` and thus switch the behaviour.
- Reading `get_type()` is a code smell. I have an idea that you're implementing a type system (Python has it's own) and that you are trying to implement polymorphism or something similar with it. This doesn't have to be a problem but it may need some scrutiny in the future.
- Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern, which is similar, and maybe a few other related patterns whether they fit your use case.